# dragging image with transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I use kineticjs example from this page http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/.
Everything works fine- i can move, drag image (kinetic.image) etc. The problem is when i press cursor on transparent area of image, dragging doesn't work then. What to do to make image draggable irrespective of that i press cursor on drawed region or transparent background of this image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing lines 121 and 122. The page is loading a script that is not being shown that changes the dragable region to the non-transparent parts. For more info [look here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-pixel-detection-with-kineticjs/)

Lines to remove:

```
animal.cache();
animal.drawHitFromCache();
```

Comment: After removing these lines dragging images is significantly more smooth :)